# First checked item in Jetpack Compose LazyColumn list is not checked, only checked after list is scrolled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

So, I have this is my code for LazyColumn list

```
val selectedTongNumber = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
LaunchedEffect(dataTongNumber.size) {
    selectedTongNumber.addAll(dataTongNumber)
}

val tongNumberList = mutableListOf(TongNumber("012345"), TongNumber("014567"), TongNumber("024568"), TongNumber("034589"), TongNumber("124567"), TongNumber("134589"), TongNumber("234567"), TongNumber("234689"), TongNumber("234789"), TongNumber("245679"))
tongNumberList.forEach { tn ->
    val availableSelected = selectedTongNumber.stream().filter { stn -> stn == tn.number }.collect(Collectors.toList())
    if (availableSelected.isNotEmpty()) {
        tn.isSelected = true
    }
}

val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LazyColumn(
    state = scrollState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(max = 150.dp)
) {
    itemsIndexed(
        items = tongNumberList.sortedByDescending { tn -> tn.isSelected },
        key = { index, tn ->
            tn.number
        }
    ) { index, tongNumber ->
        val isNumberChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(tongNumber.isSelected) }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Checkbox(
                checked = isNumberChecked.value,
                onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
                    isNumberChecked.value = isChecked
                    tongNumber.isSelected = isChecked

                    if (isChecked) {
                        selectedTongNumber.add(tongNumber.number)
                    } else {
                        selectedTongNumber.remove(tongNumber.number)
                    }

                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index = selectedTongNumber.size.minus(1))
                    }
                }
            )

            Text(
                text = tongNumber.number,
                fontFamily = fonts,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = blackPrimary
            )
        }
    }
}
```

After I run the code, I saw the first item that is supposed to be in 'checked' state is not checked. And then, I scrolled down the list, scrolled it up again, and found out the supposed to in 'checked' state item is now checked [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df2wC.gif).

I don't know where is my mistake and seems like I couldn't find any solution in the existing questions here, so I raised a question myself. Kindly help me to find the solution since I'm new in this Jetpack Compose. Thank you!